# How can I allow all these 16384 (IP range FROM & TO) IP in a single command?

Tags: iptables

I can Allow ip range by using this command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 46.43.64.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

But this range have another range From IP `46.43.64.0` To IP `46.43.127.255` as appear here: http://www.nirsoft.net/countryip/ps.html

So how can I allow all these 16384 IP in a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the netmask, or use a tool like this [Online IP CIDR calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php) if you don't have the time to do the math, neither you have memorized that `16384` addresses is equivalent to a `/18` network.

Feed this tool with the number of hosts(`16384`) and the network ip address(`46.43.64.0`) and you will have the mask: `255.255.192.0` or `46.43.64.0/18` on net CIDR notation.

Now, change your `iptables` rule to reflect this bigger net:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 46.43.64.0/18 -j ACCEPT
```

Using this CIDR notation on your rules, you can allow broader networks as you will, instead of listing all `/24` networks that integrate this wider mask.

Another way to do this, is to make a rule based on `src-range`.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 46.43.64.0-46.43.127.255 -j ACCEPT
```

I don't know how this approach would impact performance of filtering so, i would take the first option